# Delegate between controllers doesn't work. Why?

Tags: ios, swift, delegation

I try to use delegate to send data from `textField` which is in the Detail2(`ViewController`) to array which is in the `ViewController`.
I used here print method and first print show that one element has been added to the array but the second print method which is below the `ViewVillAppear()` show that array is empty. How? I want to be able to to use delegate to add data to my table.

`["sdsd"]` First print from the console
`[]`Second print from the console

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var add: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet var tv: UITableView!
var array :[String] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tv.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell") 
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segue" {
        let vc: Detail2 = segue.destination as! Detail2
        vc.delegate = self
    }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return array.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        array.remove(at: indexPath.row )
        tv.reloadData()
    }
}

func alert () {
}



 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        tv.reloadData()
        print(array)

    }

}

extension ViewController: Data {

    func tekst(data: String) {
        array.append(data)
        print(array)

    }   
}
```

and **Detail2**

```
    protocol Data {
    func tekst (data: String)
}

class Detail2: UIViewController {

    var delegate: Data? = nil
    @IBAction func btn(_ sender: Any) {

        let sb  = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Main" ) as! ViewController
        navigationController?.pushViewController(sb, animated: true)

        if delegate != nil {
            if txtfield.text != nil {

                let napis = txtfield.text
                delegate?.tekst(data: napis!)   
            }   
        }   
    }
    @IBOutlet var btn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var txtfield: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        btn.tintColor = UIColor.white
        btn.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your tekst not calling? @kuba

Comment: You are pushing a new instance of your view controller, but invoking the delegate method on the old instance. You need to use an unwind segue or pop the current view controller rather than pushing a new instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just update your function with:**

```
@IBAction func btn(_ sender: Any) {
        if delegate != nil {
        if txtfield.text != nil {
            let napis = txtfield.text
            delegate?.tekst(data: napis!)
        }

    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

    }
}
```

**Update:**

```
extension ViewController: Data {

    func tekst(data: String) {
        array.append(data)
        print(array)
        self.tv.reloadData()

    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this `delegate?.tekst(data: napis!)` inside completion handler, because you are using `navigationController`, there is no option for completion handler,So have to add `UINavigationController` extension like that:

```
extension UINavigationController {

    public func pushViewController(viewController: UIViewController,
                                   animated: Bool,
                                   completion:  (() -> Void)?) {
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock(completion)
        pushViewController(viewController, animated: animated)
        CATransaction.commit()
    }

}
```

change this

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(sb, animated: true){

    if delegate != nil {
        if txtfield.text != nil {

            let napis = txtfield.text
            delegate?.tekst(data: napis!)

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your code in Detail2 viewcontroller

```
@IBAction func btn(_ sender: Any) {

       if delegate != nil {
           if txtfield.text != nil {
             let napis = txtfield.text
             delegate?.tekst(data: napis!)
            }
        }
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `ViewController` implement the delegate method

```
 func tekst (data: String) { 
    array.append(data)
 }
```

// in detail

```
@IBAction func btn(_ sender: Any) {

    if txtfield.text != nil {

        let napis = txtfield.text
        delegate?.tekst(data: napis!)

    }

     /// dismiss detail here  don't push main again

     self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

}
```